# Referring to a theorem without numbers

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I tried to label a theorem by Theorem A. When I tried to refer it, the label A was not displaying:

```
\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem A}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm*}\label{A}
Let H be a group.
\end{thm*}

By Theorem~\ref{A} we have
```

When I tried to do this by removing *, the theorem got displayed as (Theorem A 1) and when referring it, it was diaplayed as (Theorem [1]).

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem A}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}\label{A}
Let H be a group.
\end{thm}

By Theorem~\ref{A} we have
```

**Q.** How can I create a theorem in such a way that it will be displayed with any numbering (like, Theorem K) and at the same time, it will be displayed as (Theorem K) when referring it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the reference to be what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem A}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{thm*}{\def\@currentlabel{A}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{thm*}\label{A}
Let H be a group.
\end{thm*}

By Theorem~\ref{A} we have

\end{document}
```

[image]

But it would be a nuisance to do this if you have several “named theorems”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{namedthm}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{thm*}[1]{%
  \renewcommand\thenamedthm{#1}%
  \namedthm}{\endnamedthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm*}{A}\label{A}
Let H be a group.
\end{thm*}

\begin{thm*}{B}\label{B}
Let H be a group.
\end{thm*}

By Theorem~\ref{A} and Theorem~\ref{B} we have

\end{document}
```

[image]

This works nicely with `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{namedthm}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{thm*}[1]{%
  \renewcommand\thenamedthm{#1}%
  \namedthm}{\endnamedthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm*}{A}\label{A}
Let H be a group.
\end{thm*}

\begin{thm*}{B}\label{B}
Let H be a group.
\end{thm*}

By \Cref{A} and \Cref{B} we have

\end{document}
```